# HBase create command produces no response in shell

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I am new to HBase and installed the 0.20.6 version on Cygwin as that is the requirement of my project. The master is running along with Hregionserver. However, when I try to create a table in the HBase shell, there does not seem to be any response.

When I see the list of commands, none of the table related commands are seen. How do I resolve this? Please see the screenshot.

[image: Hbase shell screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you have issued the `create` command twice - once in the HBase shell, and once in Bash - it is the second one that is giving you "command not found". Did you exit the shell deliberately? Or maybe the first `create` took effect and then exited out to Bash?

Comment: I just typed create once in the HBase shell and I had to exit the shell deliberately as there was no output. This could be a setup issue with my Hbase maybe.

Comment: OK. Do you know that HBase works on Cygwin on Windows?

Comment: Yes, that's what I read from the various forums.

Comment: I've removed the "command not found" material from your question, since that isn't a problem with your HBase shell.

Comment: If you get completely stuck, you can always run this under Linux in a small VirtualBox VM, Ubuntu would be fine.

Comment: I tried running HBase on Windows, I quickly gave up, as @halfer said, under Linux I guarantee you will get it working in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As reported on the documentation
"HBase requires that a JDK be installed"

But there is no Java on Cygwin, so you can not have a cygwin version of HBase.